# Why res.render doesn't work after res.redirect?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a `post route`, from which i am trying to redirect users to another page.
Note:- There is HTML page on front end which makes axios post request to send some data to the following route
contents of HTML

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/trial',
  data: { idToken: idToken1,
          userAttribute: user      
         },
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})
.then(function (response) {
  //handle success

  
})
.catch(function (response) {
  //handle error
  console.log(response);
});
```

post route

```
app.post('/trial', (req, res) => {
   //sone logic                    
  
    res.redirect('/trial')
        
        });
```

redirecting get route

```
app.get('/trial', (req, res) => {
            console.log('jatin');
            res.render('somepage')
            //res.send('dewdeew) /also doesn't work
            });
```

I can see console.log but not able to see my somepage being rendered.

Comment: Ajax calls do not, by themselves, display anything in the browser or change the currently displayed web page.  Your redirect response just comes back to your ajax call and to your Javascript.  If you want to do something with that response, you have to do something with it with your Javascript.  See the question yours was marked a duplicate of for further explanation.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions like what should i do? because i need to pass data form my front end to backend, and that is why i need to use axios.post. Do have any other way to pass data from HTML to backend?

Comment: Did you read the answer yours is marked a duplicate of?  Please read it.  You can capture the 302 response in your ajax and set `window.location` to a new page if you want.  Your POST to the back-end works just fine.  The question is what to do with the current web page being displayed in the browser.  Your Javascript that handles the response to the POST has to do something with the response.  Please read the question yours is marked a duplicate of.

Comment: I understood your point and i was using windows.location earlier but that resulted in asynchronous event which resulted in sometimes empty variable and then variable value.I will post another question so that you ca understand better as i am working on backend, this thing was dealt by frontend person.

Comment: Well, the solution is to process the 302 response IN YOUR AJAX code.  Not much else I can say.  We can't help with other problems that might arise from that when you've shown none of that code (and that would probably be another question anyway).  An Ajax call does not change anything in the browser display automatically.  Your Javascript has to cause any changes you want to occur.  That's how it works.